# Word for collection of scenarios

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a large collection of (plausible) scenarios either:

- In general,
- In the context of a play?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please read the guidelines in the single-word-request tag, I believe that good questions are as important as good answers.

Comment: What's wrong with this question?  I dont understand

Comment: Can you write a sample sentence IN the question, showing how this word would be used? Can you explain why you need this word? And, a large collection of scenarios is, to my mind, vague. Can you give more examples?

Comment: It's to name a mathematical object.  So the context is a bit difficult to explain, but I may say it would be the collection of all possible outcomes of a random variable.

Comment: @KannE this is good but is there a word that's less ...well hypothetical and more tangible?

Comment: I don't know a term for this from the theater, but from music there's a term: *theme and variations* or *variations on a theme*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase **all possible outcomes**, which was used in a comment under the question, would be the most well known in plain language.

But a technical term for this is **sample space**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space):

> In probability theory, the **sample space** of an experiment or random trial is the set of all possible outcomes or results of that experiment. A sample space is usually denoted using set notation, and the possible ordered outcomes are listed as elements in the set. It is common to refer to a sample space by the labels S, Ω, or U (for "universal set").

If you were to use *sample space* in a play, I would not assume that all (or even most) audience members would understand its meaning. Most likely, there would be a line of dialogue that explained it as *all possible outcomes* before using it regularly.